# Change study height in Tradingview charting library?

Tags: trading, tradingview-api

After creating a new study and adding it to my chart with:

```
widget.chart().createStudy("abcd crypto index", false, true);
```

How can I change the height of the study? Is there a similar way like with the volume?

```
overrides: {
    "volumePaneSize": "medium",
    ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the height of all panes is available in Charting Library version 1.15 (currently the `unstable` branch) by accessing the specific pane using the Pane API - `widget.chart().getPanes()`

via https://github.com/tradingview/charting_library/wiki/Pane-Api (access to Charting Library private repo required to view wiki)

**getHeight()**

Starting from version 1.15.

Returns the pane's height.

**setHeight()**

Starting from version 1.15.

Sets the pane's height.